# How get video view count youtube api with Nodejs

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

since a few days I have been looking for information on how I can get the count of reproductions of a particular YouTube video. The google documentation of how to do it with Nodejs does not clarify the doubt. If any of you knows how to help me. I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the following URL in NodeJS and extract the `viewCount` value: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY